# Function that can compare Data from 2 dataframs (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have to compare 2 dataframes and to export data from them into creating a new dataframe :

- The 2 dataframes (df_EX and df_VE), they have exactly the same colums but not same number of rows.
- There is a column named ('MT_NET' or the 4th) that has negatif data in EX and positif data in VE, I have to code a function that takes the data without taking into account the sign.
- Exemple if I have a row that has -500 in EX and another 500 VE (same amount) and same transaction code in the 2nd column ("NUMBER"), I have to extract both of the rows into a new dataframe.

I could really use your help, thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with some data table/ data frame ?

Comment: I got 2 data frames where there is 6 columns, the 5th named MT_NET contains the data I need to work with. In the second data frames (EX) I've got only negatifs data for MT_NET and in the first positifs data. However there is some rows that are the same with the same amount but with a negatif sign. The function has to find these rows and copy then into a new dataframe to clean the EX/VE dataframes.